# A white noise process which does not consist of independent random variables?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, independence

I know the definition of a white noise $\{u_t\}$ (see below), but I cannot see how to find an example of a white noise which is serially dependent, e.g. where $u_t$ depends on the value of $u_{t-1}$. Can someone provide an example of a dependent white noise process?

*Definition of a white noise process.* The stochastic process $\{u_t\}$ is white noise if and only if (1) $E(u_t)=0$ and (2) $E(u_tu_{t+k})=\sigma^2\textbf{1}\{k=0\}$, where $\textbf{1}\{k=0\} =1$ if $k=0$ and $0$ otherwise,  and where $\sigma>0$ is finite.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is inspired by [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent#A_symmetric_example).

We say a random variable $W$ follows the [Rademacher distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher_distribution) if $\mathbb{P}(W = 1) = 0.5$ and $\mathbb{P}(W = -1) = 0.5$. Let $u_0 \sim N(0, 1)$ and $u_t = u_{t-1}w_t$ where $\{w_t\}$ are i.i.d and follow the Rademacher distribution.

Then by the arguments in the first wiki page, we know that all $u_t$ have the same distribution $N(0, 1)$ and are serially uncorrelated, but $u_t$ is certainly dependent on $u_{t-1}$.